# How do you process xml columns and check every xml entries with MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml

```
<Standard>
  <Equip Cat="Hardware">10 TB Disk</Equip>
  <Equip Cat="Hardware">USB 2.0</Equip>
</Standard>
```

I have a column called XML in a table called Product. The type is XML(.), and I am wondering how I can process the xml column.

The big issue is that I have no idea how to do a foreach in a XML column.

I want to add a row if my stored procedure detects the substring "10 TB" inside of the category "Hardware"inside the table called ProductFeature with the id from table Product in the column id and true inside of the column HighDiskSpace.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Why do you need a "FOR EACH" at all? Seems like you just need some XQUERY to the `Standard/Equip` node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a conceptual example for you.

It is using XQuery `.exist()` method. Its XPath predicate expression satisfies your question requirements. Both variables, `@cat` and `@searchString`, could be your stored procedure parameters.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @Product TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @Product (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<Standard>
  <Equip Cat="Hardware">10 TB Disk</Equip>
  <Equip Cat="Hardware">USB 2.0</Equip>
</Standard>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @cat VARCHAR(30) = 'Hardware'
    , @searchString VARCHAR(30) = '10 TB';

SELECT * 
FROM @Product
WHERE xmldata.exist('(/Standard/Equip[@Cat=sql:variable("@cat") 
    and contains(./text()[1], sql:variable("@searchString"))])[1]') = 1;
```